# How do I get the Minecraft GUI scale to go back to Auto?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been playing Minecraft, and I went into the settings to see what could be changed. I was in display and I saw the GUI scale was set to "Auto", which was fairly large. I cycled through the scales until I got back to auto, but the GUI scale was stuck at normal size and wouldn't allow me to make it large again. I know this isn't such a big problem, but I really like big font and this is a constant bother to me.

Comment: and yes i have tried restarting my computer

Comment: resize the minecraft window, make the window smaller if you want the GUI to be large and make the window larger if you want the GUI to be small

Comment: but is there a way i can go full screen and have a large GUI because thats how it always was until i messed with it

Comment: go fullscreen, and change the setting to large instead of auto, in that order, let me know if it works

Comment: What snapshot are you playing in? If any at all?

Comment: it did not work ender

Comment: im sorry can you give me the definition of snapshot

Comment: @Neon_Toaster The latest development version of minecraft, ie: 14w18b

Comment: all i know is i have the latest version

Comment: @Neon_Toaster I'm exrememly busy with work and will be for roughly the next week, but keep checking back here, myself or another will have you a solution eventually.

Comment: @Neon_Toaster my solution works for me, but I do not have the latest version of minecraft because I play modded, I'm going to update to the latest version and try again.

Comment: @Neon_Toaster It should tell you in the game menu which version you are using in the bottom left corner. (Also, is my username too long for some people?)

Answer (score 1):

In all tests simply putting my Minecraft window to fullscreen and then **changing the GUI mode in the options** allows me to have large buttons and font with a fullscreen minecraft.

I have tried both older and the most updated stable released version of minecraft. (no snapshots)

If this does not work for you for some reason my assumption would be your either doing it wrong unawares, or there is something wrong with your files.

Comment: Thank you all for trying to help but I have gotten used to it

Answer (score 1):

Simple fix for this. Go into the minecraft folder and delete the settings.txt file. Restart minecraft and it'll be back to normal.